# Replace a string which is present on first line in UNIX file

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I would like to replace a string which is present on the first line though it is there on rest of the lines in the file as well. How can i do that through a shell script? Can someone help me regarding this. My code is as below. I am extracting the first line from the file and after that I am not sure how to do a replace. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Guys -I would like to replace a string present in $line and write the new line into the same file at same place.

**Code:**

```
while read line
do
        if [[ $v_counter == 0 ]] then
                echo "$line"

                v_counter=$(($v_counter + 1));
        fi
done < "$v_Full_File_Nm"
```

**Sample data:**

**Input**

```
    BUXT_CMPID|MEDICAL_RECORD_NUM|FACILITY_ID|PATIENT_LAST_NAME|PATIENT_FIRST_NAME|HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_1|HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_2|HOME_CITY|HOME_STATE|HOME_ZIP|MOSAIC_CODE|MOSAIC_DESC|DRIVE_TIME| buxt_pt_apnd_20140624_head_5records.txt
100106086|5000120878|7141|HARRIS|NEDRA|6246 PARALLEL PKWY||KANSAS CITY|KS|66102|S71|Tough Times|2|buxt_pt_apnd_20140624_head_5records.txt
```

**Output**

```
BUXT_CMPID|MEDICAL_RECORD_NUM|FACILITY_ID|PATIENT_LAST_NAME|PATIENT_FIRST_NAME|HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_1|HOME_ADDRESS_LINE_2|HOME_CITY|HOME_STATE|HOME_ZIP|MOSAIC_CODE|MOSAIC_DESC|DRIVE_TIME| SRC_FILE_NM
100106086|5000120878|7141|HARRIS|NEDRA|6246 PARALLEL PKWY||KANSAS CITY|KS|66102|S71|Tough Times|2|buxt_pt_apnd_20140624_head_5records.txt
```

From the above sample data I need to replace **buxt_pt_apnd_20140624_head_5records.txt** **with SRC_FILE_NAME** string.

Comment: The UNIX shell is an environment from which to call tools. The UNIX tool to manipulate text files is awk. So, write an awk script and call it from shell.

Comment: Your posted sample data only contains 1 line, but it sounded in your text like it was important for a solution to NOT replace strings in subsequent lines so you should post some sample input/output tht demonstrates that aspect of your requirements. ALso - what if the target string appears multiple times on your first line? What if it appears as part of another string?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not use `sed`?

```
sed -e '1s/fred/frog/' yourfile
```

will replace `fred` with `frog` on line 1.

If your 'string' is a variable, you can do this to get the variable expanded:

```
sed -e "1s/$varA/$varB/" yourfile
```

If you want to do it in place and change your file, add `-i` before `-e`.

Comment: That does not replaces a string, it replaces a regular expression which is a very different situation.

Comment: @EdMorton - while you are strictly speaking correct, I think that for the purpose of this question, `sed` is fine as a tool. It seems simpler than `awk`.

Comment: I don't think we should guess at what characters the OPs strings may or may not contain. The one example posted so far contains an RE metacharacter. The equivalent to the above sed script in awk would be `awk 'NR==1{sub(/fred/,"frog")}1' yourfile` which is no more complicated than the sed solution, you just wouldn't write that in awk because unlike sed which cannot support strings, you have the option in awk of actually working on strings and so not relying on just the hope that the input data will never contain RE metacharacters. It would be nice if there was a briefer syntax but there's not.

Comment: @EdMorton I understood a string to be `a bunch of characters/digits` and `fred` seems to me, at least, to be a bunch of characters/digits.

Comment: In programming, a string is defined by context as well as content. In this case in the context of sed search space, a bunch of characters/digits is a regular expression not a string. If you were trying to replace the bunch of characters/digits `.*` with `foo` in the line `this is .* location` in the awk solution I posted the output would be `this is foo location` while in your sed solution the output would be just `foo`.

Comment: @EdMorton Very drôle! 

Comment: I've just seen it happen so many times where someone has a sed script to replace "strings" and it works great for a long time until one day they hit that one case they never saw coming where they have just the wrong combination of RE metacharacters in their "string" and so it bites them in the ass and mangles their data. Its a loaded gun...

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mark.. But when i run your command and try writing the data into a new file it writes the source file into the target. sed -e '1s/$v_src_file_nm/SRC_FILE_NM/' $v_Full_File_Nm > $v_Src_File_Full_Nm

Comment: @SOaddict If your string is in a variable, you will need to use `"` in place of `'` so that the variable gets expanded. I will update the answer.

Comment: ...and just be aware that in addition to various RE metacharacters (., *, +, ?, (, ), [, ], |, \ in some locations, etc.), your "string" cannot contain "/"s now either.

Comment: Oh, and your replacement "string" can't contain `/`s or `&`s or `\ `s followed by digits or at the end of the string either. I'm sure there's other character combinations I haven't thought of that will also bite you but I won't post any more about it - you get the idea...

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -v old="string1" -v new="string2" '
NR==1 && (idx=index($0,old)) {
    $0 = substr($0,1,idx-1) new substr($0,idx+length(old))
}
1' file > /usr/tmp/tmp$$ && mv /usr/tmp/tmp$$ file
```

The above will replace `string1` with `string2` only when it appears in the first line of `file`.

Any solution posted that uses awk but does not use `index` will not work in general. Same for any solution posted that uses sed. The reason is that those would work on REs, not strings and so behave undesirably for string replacement depending what characters are present in `string1`.

Looks like the OPs going with a sed RE-replacement solution so this is just for anyone else looking to replace a string: Here's what a string replacement function would look like if youd rather not have it inline:

```
awk -v old="string1" -v new="string2" '
function strsub(old,new,tgt,     idx) {
    if ( idx = index(tgt,old) ) {
        tgt = substr(tgt,1,idx-1) new substr(tgt,idx+length(old))
    }
    return tgt
}
NR==1 { $0 = strsub(old,new,$0) }
1' file
```

Comment: Is there a `-i` type option for `awk` like there is for `sed`?

Comment: Yes, newer releases of GNU awk have `-i inplace` but, like sed, that just hides the fact you're using a tmp file, it doesn't change the fact that you are using one.

Comment: @SOaddict thanks. The sed "solution" is certainly briefer, but honestly it's a jack-in-the-box since there's all sorts of characters in all sorts of combinations in the search and replacement "strings" that will completely mess up your files in bizarre ways. If you're lucky they'll produce a syntax error but if not they'll just quietly replace the wrong string and/or replace the right string with the wrong replacement text. If this is for a school project then worst case your teacher will ding you but if this is for a real business application I would avoid that sed solution for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

A bash solution:

```
file="afile.txt"
str="hello"
repl="goodbye"

IFS= read -r line < "$file"
line=${line/$str/$repl}

tmpfile="/usr/tmp/$file.$$.tmp"

{
  echo "$line"
  tail -n+2 "$file"
} > "$tmpfile" && mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
```

Note that `$str` above will be interpreted as a "pattern" (a simple kind of regex) where `*` matches any number of any characters, `?` matches any single character, `[abc]` matches any one of the characters in the brackets, and `[^abc]` (or `[!abc]`) matches any one character *not* in the brackets. See [Pattern-Matching](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching)

Comment: That does not replaces a string, it replaces a regular expression which is a very different situation.

Comment: @EdMorton Changed to a `bash` solution. Thanks for the pointer.

Comment: Isn't that still operating on REs instead of strings though? It has additional problems now where, for example, it will replace the string `\t` with a literal tab character anywhere on the input line and strip any leading/trailing white space and if you fail to create the tmp file you will zap the contents of your original file.

Comment: @EdMorton I'm not sure how it will replace \t with a tab (`echo` only does that with the `-e` switch, for instance, and `read` doesn't seem to do that at all). `read` can be forced to *not* strip leading/trailing whitespace by setting `IFS` to the null string. Stopping it clobbering the original file is easy enough (I think). But you're right that the replace command uses a kind of regex (where * and ? and [...] are special), so that's no good. I'm looking at alternatives now...

Comment: read interprets escape sequences like `\t` unless you add the `-r` flag for `raw`. Every time you use `read` you should write `IFS= read -r ...` unless you have a very specific reason not to and understand all of the caveats, kinda like you should always quote your variables. Hmm, maybe without -r read just strips the backslashes, I can never remember. Anyway, it's too bad the default behavior in shell never seems to be to just leave the frickin' text alone as you'd normally want, but I suppose greater minds than mine have a reason for it...